# Password Protection in Outlook 2010 Exchange Server

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

Is there a way to set up a password on launch of Outlook 2010 with only an Exchange server account set up inside? Have been able to do it with a .pst file but not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

- In Outlook 2010:

  - Select the File tab.
  - Click the Account Settings button.
  - From the drop-down list, select Account Settings....
- Select your Exchange account.
- If prompted, in the Password: text box, type your password.
- Click the Change... button.
- Click the More Settings... button.
- Select the Security tab.
- Place a check in the appropriate check box.

  - In 2003, place a check in the Always prompt for user name and password check box.
  - In 2007/2010, place a check in the Always prompt for logon credentials check box.
- Click OK.
- Click the Cancel button.
- In 2007/2010, click the Close button.
- Restart Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Exchange MAPI provider uses the identity of the current Windows user to authenticate.
If you are logged in as a user other than the mailbox owner, it will prompt you.
Also note that the OST store (the cached local store) is not password protected: even if you do not have a live connection to the mailbox, the locally cached messages will still be visible.

Comment: You can set Outlook to connect in "Online" mode to avoid the OST cache.